# JavaScript ajax function set to Synchronus - returns empty object

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I did a bit of research but could not find an example that fit this situation. Here is my javascript code:

```
function obtainChartData(chart) {
    "use strict";
    $.ajax({
        url: 'server/ExtractTelemetry.php',
        type: "POST",
        async: false,
        data: JSON.stringify(chart),
        success: function (data) {
            var x = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
            alert(typeof x); //SHOWS AS "object"
            return x;
        }
    });
}
```

And then this function receives it:

```
$("#loadChart").click(function () {
    ...
    data = obtainChartData(newChart);
    alert(typeof data); //SHOWS AS "undefined"
    ...
});
```

If the ajax call is set to async, then I would understand why this would happen, but in the situation "data" is not assigned until the function returns. So why is it showing as undefined?

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: @unixarmy "jquery-1.11.3.min"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as a synchronous AJAX call (AJAX stands for "asynchronous JavaScript and XML").

The return value of your `success` function is simply ignored by jQuery.

You just found the very basic problem everyone with javascript ever had -- there will be asynchronous code (such as AJAX code) somewhere in your application, and you will have to make all of your code that uses this function asynchronous too.

There are a lot of ideas people had since this problem emerged, e.g. Promises and the new ES6 `await/async` keywords. To keep it simple, for now, you could pass a callback to `obtainChartData` and have that handle the result:

```
function obtainChartData(chart, callback) {
    "use strict";
    $.ajax({
        url: 'server/ExtractTelemetry.php',
        type: "POST",
        async: false,
        data: JSON.stringify(chart),
        success: function (data) {
            var x = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
            alert(typeof x); //SHOWS AS "object"
            callback(x); // instead of return!
        }
    });
}

$("#loadChart").click(function () {
    ...
    obtainChartData(newChart, function (data) {
        alert(typeof data);
    });
    ...
});
```

Comment: The code appears to make sense but I am not sure why this method does not work. The second alert() is not firing. I attempted to add another alert in there with an empty string and it did not fire either. Thank you for the explanation though.

Answer (score 1):

From success call your callback function

```
success: function (data) {
            var x = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
            alert(typeof x); //SHOWS AS "object"
            return resFun(x);
        }

function resFun(data){
  alert(typeof data);// Now you get the object

}
```